# Empty Adress bar on website with a chrome extension

Tags: html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to program a Chrome extension, that redirects to a website, when a new tab is opened. It would be amazing, if the address bar would be empty and selected (ready for a google search). Does anyone of you know if this is possible and if so, what would be the code (in the json or html file) to do so?

```
in „manifest.json“ I have:

{
"name": "NewpageOR",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "0.1",
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
"newtab": "index.html"
}
}


In „index.html“ I have:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Meta Tag</title>
<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "0; url = https://www.reddit.com" />
</head>
</html>
```

what would be the codeline for an empty adress bar and where do I need to put this? Sorry for this basic question I'm a newbie and trying to learn. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) instead of `meta`

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfect! However now I have a blank page... How can I redirect to a webpage?

Comment: Sounds like you're not using it correctly. Make a separate js file, load it in your html. Inside js file use `chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: 'https://www.reddit.com'}))`

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much. Complete newbie as said... ;-) thanks a lot